# Java - How to read output from 7z?

Tags: java, output, 7zip

Hy.

I've created a routine that read .tgz files from a directory and unzip each one. I'm using

```
Process zip01 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("LINE OF COMMAND");
```

and

```
exitVal = zip01.waitFor();
```

I,m using 7z.exe from its folder to decompress and compress files. The command line is working fine. Now, I what to read the percentage of the decompress and throw it into a textfield or a textarea. The graphics part are ok too, s well all the routine. The only dificult is to get the realtime percentage of the 7z. is there some way to read and show it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with 7zip's CLI functionality, but if it provides this via standard out, you can definitely get that.
`BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zip01.getInputStream()));`


`BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
     InputStreamReader(zip01.getErrorStream()));`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the output of your process like this:

```
Process zip01 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("LINE OF COMMAND");

BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zip01.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = output.readLine()) != null) {

    /* process lines */
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Robert, but this is not what I need. I need a realtime percentage of the zipping process. This solution worked for another question, but Its solution only shows the final of the process for this question.

Comment: So you're looking for somebody to fill in the "process lines" bit for you?